# Java class xml vs java bean autowiring

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired, spring-java-config

In xml defined beans you can define two classes like this

```
<bean id="classA" class="ex.ClassA"/>

<bean id="classB" class="ex.classB"/>
```

Then in your java implementation you can autowire the constructor of one of the classes in example

```
public class ClassA {
@autowired
public(ClassB classB){
this.classB = classB;
}
```

Now how does one do that with java config beans since in example

```
@Bean
public ClassA classA(){
return new ClassB();
}

@Bean
public ClassB classB(){
return new ClassB()
}
```

the compiler would warn that Class a does not have any such constructor, how does one do that in java, with autowiring?

Thanks all

Comment: You appear to have an idiosyncratic definition of "autowiring", and it would be helpful for you to explain exactly what you want in your question.

Comment: I would want to use the power of autowiring even though I prefer to use java configs. And not have to hardcode which bean is connected to another

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-injecting-dependencies

Note that the `ClassB` bean is implicitly a singleton. The use of the annotation `@Configuration` on the `Config` class ensures that Spring returns the singleton instance of the `ClassB` bean in the `classB()` call.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ClassA classA(){
        return new ClassA( classB() );
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB(){
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Or you may prefer this approach (Spring 4.2.1+ required)

```
@Configuration
@Import(ClassA.class)
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ClassB classB(){
        return new ClassB();
    }
}

@Component
public class ClassA {
    @Autowired
    public ClassA(ClassB classB) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That would not be autowired, that would be the same as defining constructor arguments in the xml def.

Comment: There is not a one-to-one correspondence between all features of xml and java configuration. The choice is between one style or the other.

Comment: Ok I'll take that answer! So what you are saying is there is no way to do that with java configs, you would basically have to pass the bean to another. So the bean definition would have to change in regards to the pojos. Thanks

Comment: With the latest Spring version, you can @Import components in addition to configuration classes. With that, you can import ClassA and have it autowired with the ClassB bean. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the beans you want as parameters to the `@Bean` method, or use component scanning to create the dependent bean implicitly.

Comment: The question was how to use autowiring in the same manner as with xml def. Sure you can pass them along in the bean def. but then that wouldn't be autowired

Comment: Although I would appreciate if you elaborated on the component scan and an example how that would be used thanks

Comment: @MRK187 The method parameters are what's autowired in an `@Bean` method.

Comment: Yes great that's another way to do it. Thanks